# How to return from ifpresent in java8 for Optional<T> null pointer checks?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, option-type

I have this unsafe code that could throw nullPtr exceptions:

```
Type t = objParam.getProject().getType();
```

How can I use java 8 optional and ifpresent()to return the least amount of code safely (one liner)?

```
// How can I modify this  to return from the ifPresent()...or a better way in 
// java8?  how can I just return a string from the ifPresent() method?
// instead of on a separate if(...isPresent) <make the assignment>?
//
Optional<Obj> obj = Optional.ofNullable(objParam);
Optional<String> typeName = obj
.map(Project::getProject)
.map(Type::getType).ifPresent().getName(); // ??? how to get the type name ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality of `Optional.map` is that it returns an `Optional` that only has a value if the original variable also `isPresent`. So I suspect you just want:

```
obj.map(Obj::getProject).map(Project::getType).map(Type::getName);
```

Note that `ifPresent` has an entirely different purpose: it is to allow a `Consumer` to `accept` a value only if one is present. So for something like:

```
...map(Type::getName).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: +1. @JaJ: In particular, note from this answer that it is (for example) `Obj::getProject`, not `Project::getProject`: the part before the `::` is the type on which the method is defined, *not* the type that the method returns. (The compiler can tell the latter on its own.)

Comment: @sprinter, thanks! so all of this is all null pointer exception safe, no?

Comment: @JaJ Yes. As long as your original `obj` is created with a `Optional.ofNullable` then it's guaranteed to not be `null`. All the `map` method calls will then always return an `Optional` as well. So yes this is a much safer way of dealing with values that might not be present.